# When adding new Wordpress page, choose which category posts will be displayed?

Tags: wordpress

Im aware that i can make a custom page template and choose there what category posts is displayed on that spesific page.

What im after for would be some sort of way to choose the category when creating a new page, and all of these pages would use the same page template.

I tried to search plugins etc but didn't find any. Is there a good plugin / other way to do this?

Ideal would be for example that when user is creating new page, there would be a dropdown menu where he/she could choose what posts are displayed on the page.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the posts actually in the page (vs a sidebar)? And would they be along with any other content that the user would enter in the page?

If so I would think there would be a plugin that allows the user to put a shortcode specifying the category of posts they wanted and probably some limit on the number.

Comment: only the posts and on a "normal" page. Basically like "news" page would just list posts under "news" category :)

Comment: do you mean something like this:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/
I haven't used it but it looks like what you are describing

Comment: it could be, ill have to think if its easy enough to use for my purpose, thanks anyway :)

Comment: if you want something as easy as a dropdown select, you are really talking about a plugin or adding some code to your theme. the theme/plugin would add a metabox or an option to an existing metabox when viewing pages. then it would hook into the

Comment: ugg. it cut me off.
if you want something as easy as a dropdown select, you are really talking about a plugin or adding some code to your theme. the theme/plugin could add a metabox or an option to an existing metabox when viewing pages. see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) for adding a metabox.
then I think you would hook in right when page content was being fetched and add in your selection of posts. see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) for an example of manipulating page content.